# Webkit notifications requestPermission function doesn't work

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, notifications, html5-notifications

I am trying to implement support for WebKit's native desktop notifications on my site. When I try to ask for user's permission to use the notifications, absolutely nothing happens. For example, the following HTML does not prompt Chrome to ask me for permission:

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<body>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
    <script>
        window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that there is no problem with my version of Chrome because other sites (e.g. http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/notifications/quick/) work perfectly fine: I can see both the prompt and the subsequent notifications.

Comment: Even if you get the permission bar to pop-up, notifications still won't display if you work off a local file:/// URL. After you move the file to an http:// location, `window.webkitNotifications.createNotification.show()` will display the notification.

Comment: How do we test locally then? @DanDascalescu

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Check the specification at [chromium api docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification). You can call it only as a feedback to user gesture/action - mouse click etc.

> requestPermission Requests that the
>   user agent ask the user for permission
>   to show notifications from scripts. 
>   **This method should only be called
>   while handling a user gesture**; in
>   other circumstances it will have no
>   effect. This method is asynchronous. 
>   The function provided in callback will
>   be invoked when the user has responded
>   to the permission request.  If the
>   current permission level is
>   PERMISSION_DENIED, the user agent may
>   take no action in response to
>   requestPermission.

**UPDATE 2014-10-01**: In Chrome 37, [the user gesture requirement was removed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=274284#c45). It should now be possible to request permission to display notifications at any moment. If you wish to target older versions of Chrome as well (eg. in a corporate environment), you'll probably need to continue relying on user gesture events.

Comment: The example on this page is only requesting permission on a 'click' event, yet it still does not work: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/

Comment: if you check your errors console you'll find that twitter changed their API and the demo is now broken

Comment: The button that says "Set notification permissions for this page" doesn't work either.

Comment: works for me alright - a ribbon pops up in chrome 24 and asks you to allow for notifications - also if you allowed it once it isn't going to pop up anymore you'd need to clean it up in settings (chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications)

Comment: Right under the button it specifically says: "Use this button if you also want to reset the permissions". The button doesn't do anything for me regardless of what "exceptions" I have listed for Notifications in Chrome.

Comment: example is broken anyway - got link to api docs in the answer and write your example

Answer (score 2):

For checking Notification on local file (file://) permission will popup but notification wont work on chrome.

As a work around you can change

> Content setting > Notification > Allow All websites to show notification

Shortest code to show notification

```
var notification = new Notification("YOUR MESSAGE");
```