# Desktop notifications allowing not working on chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, notifications

So i want my web page to promt for validation on desktop notifications when it loads. So i added onload in body...

```
<body onload="setAllowNotification() return false;">
```

This works jsut fine on mozilla firefox but in Google chrome it doesn't show the question. But if i call that function like this, it works.

```
<a onclick="setAllowNotification(); return false;" href="#">Click to set allow notifications</a>
```

If it helps my setAllowNotification function:

```
function setAllowNotification()
    {
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(permissionGranted);
    }
```

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try adding a semicolon to your onload event inline code:</strike>

Check this answer actually...

[Webkit notifications requestPermission function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040107/webkit-notifications-requestpermission-function-doesnt-work)

You can only use it as part of a response to a user action - i.e. you cannot do it "onload"

Comment: so what's the best way to do this kind of stuf? And why does is work in firefox?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert on it, but it's only a draft specification so each browser will have its own implementation which may be slightly different to other browsers. I'd hazard a guess that Firefox allows you to do it `onload` but Chrome doesn't. Perhaps you could try triggering the `click` event in the `onload` event? It **might** fool Chrome, but I doubt it.