# Get popup notification on browser first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image: PopUp Notification]

Hello everyone,

I need popup notification like facebook notification in above image for first time on opening the site on browser and once it allow I will store in cookie for future use.
I am thinking in core javascript to built this but unable to achieve it.

Any help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried onload?

Comment: Yes but its coming a window popup ? but i need something like this for allow and block notification.

Comment: I believe the thing you are looking for is browser permission API.

Comment: I guess yes. can you please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use browser's Notification Api.

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
window.confirm("your warning text here")
```

on page load function you can write this

```
var x =window.confirm("your warning text here")
```

If user selects ok value of x will be true and on cancel it will be false
based on this value you can write your logic

Or you can use this link may be helpful

[Desktop notifications allowing not working on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421667/desktop-notifications-allowing-not-working-on-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `confirm()`

```
var x = confirm("Notification!");
    if (x == true) {
        alert("OK");
    }
    else {
        alert("Cancel");
    }
```