# Notification.requestPermission is undefined from ServiceWorker execution file. Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, service-worker

I faced an issue where `Notification.requestPermission` doesn't fire from my `ServiceWorker` handler.

Interesting thing, that if try to use `Notification.requestPermission` from browser console it works fine and I have see the notification request in top of the Chrome browser window.

by: `Notification.requestPermission().then(res => console.log(res))` . But the same throw me an error during execution from `ServiceWorker` file, like:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.Notification.requestPermission is not a function

So, anyone maybe know what is wrong? I have already seen these posts on SoW:

1. [Webkit notifications requestPermission function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040107/webkit-notifications-requestpermission-function-doesnt-work)
2. [Desktop notifications allowing not working on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421667/desktop-notifications-allowing-not-working-on-chrome)

But they does not solve my problem...

My SW `push` part of code where I use notifications:

```
  self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log(self.Notification, Notification.requestPermission)
    self.Notification.requestPermission().then(res => console.log(res))

    if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
      console.log('Permission wasn\'t granted. Allow a retry.');
     return;
    }

    if (Notification.permission === 'default') {
      console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
      return;
    }

    console.log('The permission request is granted!');

    try {
      event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(event && event.data && event.data.text() || 'Some Notification Here!')
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(`Error in SW: ${e}`)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope, still an issue for me...

Comment: i got to make it work but without using request permission method.

Comment: can u share your idea here?

Comment: I think Notification.requestPermission not working here, because its need user activity. Check Notification.permission is working.

Comment: Did anybody come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @HVenom see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who those who're looking for an answer here it's easy - you shall run `Notification.requestPermission` **only** **before** `DOMContentLoaded` phase is finished.

Otherwise, the browser won't let you request this permission due to the finished page resourced load.

Comment: And how do you propose we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the accepted answer Also as @user706420 mentioned in the comments if the only use case is just to get the status of permission instead of using `Notification.requestPermission()` (which might have been used from the main thread to request permission for the first time when the users arrive at your app).

one can use `Notification.permission` to check the current status of the permission from within service worker just before showing the notification since permission can be changed at any time by the user.

Here is a snippet:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if(Notification.permission === 'granted'){
     self.registration.showNotification()
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you can check the permission at any time even afterward. Besides **by default**, all the **notification permissions are disabled** to show in every browser. So don't rely fully on this approach if you wanna show some notify for end-user eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Those who want a more straightforward answer:
Go to the src/serviceWorkerRegistration.js
add the following code inside register(config) function:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(res=>{
    if(Notification.permission=='granted'){
        console.log("Granted permission")
        return
    }
    console.log(res)
})
```

Put the above code mentioned inside question in public/custom-sw.js file except those requestPermissions.

```
self.addEventListener('push',e=>{
    console.log(self.Notification)
    // self.Notification.requestPermission().then(res=>console.log(res))

    if(self.Notification.permission == 'denied'){
        console.log("Permission wan't granted")
        
        return;
    }

    if(self.Notification.permission == 'default'){
        console.log("The permission request was dismissed")
    }

    console.log("The permission request was granted!")

    try{
        const data = e.data.json()
        const options = {
            body: data.body
        }
        e.waitUntil(
            self.registration.showNotification(data.title,options)
        )
    }catch(err){
        throw new Error(`Error in SW: ${e}`)
    }
})
```

Thank You!