# Does Notification HTML5 work in local in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to create a notification in Chrome.
I have write this simple code but there is notification shown in CHrome whereas `checkPermission()` return well `0`.

I do the same thing than this website (example), which works fine in my Chrome browser.

```
if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
  window.webkitNotifications.createNotification("icon.png", "title", "text").show();
} else {
  window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
}
```

Where is the problem ?

**[EDIT : Problem fixed]**

In fact, i allows to show notification from all website in Chrome settings, and now, it works fine !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request permission only work on a user gesture (see below question, and quote from the docs).

In short you need to register a click event or something similar **then** request permission.

```
document.querySelector('#show_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) { // 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED

    var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
        'icon.png', 'Notification Title', 'Notification content...');
      notification.show();
  } else {
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
  }
}, false);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Qhh/1/)

> [Webkit notifications requestPermission function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040107/webkit-notifications-requestpermission-function-doesnt-work)
>   requestPermission Requests that the user agent ask the user for
>   permission to show notifications from scripts. This method should only
>   be called while handling a user gesture; in other circumstances it
>   will have no effect. This method is asynchronous. The function
>   provided in callback will be invoked when the user has responded to
>   the permission request. If the current permission level is
>   PERMISSION_DENIED, the user agent may take no action in response to
>   requestPermission.